# kdb q - create 2d buckets for positive integers

Tags: kdb

I am trying create 2d buckets in q

Given a 2d grid

```
5 o---o---o
  |   |   |
3 o---o---o
  |   |   |
0 o---o---o
  0   3   5
```

each node on the grid defines the boundary of 2d buckets for positive integers. For example the center node would contain tuples `(x;y)` where `3<=x<5` and `3<=y<5`. The nine buckets are indexed from `0,...,8`.

The way I tried to implemented this in q is

```
bucketidx:{((0 3 5i) cross (0 3 5i)) bin "i"$(first x;last x)}
```

To traverse through the buckets:

```
bucketidx each ((0 3 5i) cross (0 3 5i))
/0j, 1j, 2j, 3j, 4j, 5j, 6j, 7j, 8j
```

However I get a strange behavior on `bucketidx 6 0`. I expect this to be in the upper left node

`(5<=y) and (x=0)`

but it returns index `8` which would be the upper right node. I hope it is clear what I am trying to do.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because of the bin behavior.

Binary search returns the index of the last item in x which is <=y

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/search/#bin-binr

Your list is :

```
    q) a:(0 3 5i) cross (0 3 5i)
    q) a / (0 0; 0 3;0 5;3 0; 3 3; 3 5;5 0;5 3; 5 5)
```

You are searching (6 0) in this list using bin function and last item in that list which is <=(6;0) is (5;5) and index of that item is 8.

```
    q) a bin 6 0 / 8
```

thats the reason you are getting 8.

I think 'tuple with bin' approach is not the right way to go for this problem.

You could use something similar to below idea. First argument to function is X coordinate and second is Y coordinate.

```
 q) node:{b:0 3 5;(b bin x)+3*b bin y}
 q) node[0;6] / 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use a dictionary with sorted attribute, which makes it a step function.

```
q)d:`s#0 3 5!0 1 2
q)3 sv' d@(0 3 5i) cross (0 3 5i)
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
q)3 sv' d@enlist 6 0
,6
```